# class declaration and definition in Java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

```
public class Tree<T> 
{
    private Node<T> root;

    public Tree(T rootData)
    {
         root = new Node<T>();
         root.data = rootData;
         root.children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    }
}
```

I found a code in which the class is declared like this? What does  mean?

Comment: Which part of it are you having difficulty understanding?

Comment: It is about the [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) type.

Comment: I did not understand the <T> part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class is for a Tree, which is a common data structure used to store things in a tree like form (each part of the tree is called a "node", and then each node can have a child node to its left or right [like this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Unbalanced_binary_tree.svg).

The generic parameter T means we can create a tree of any type, and all the nodes in that tree will need to be of that same type.

The constructor we see allows us to create a new Node (the top of the tree), initialise it with the rootData, and create a list of children which will be all of the nodes below this root node.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic. When instantiating a `Tree` you can provide a class such as `Tree<String>` that will be used for the Node in a similar way, and as the constructor parameter type.